# Dynamic Coroutine name

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coroutine

How can I make the name of the Coroutine dynamic?
I use this to make targets die automatically after a few seconds:

```
void InitiateKill(int i)
{
   //i is the number of the target
   StartCoroutine(TargetDie(i, timeAlive/1000));
   //some other stuff
}
```

When the target is killed before this timer ends, I obviously get an error because it can't kill the target again.

That's why I want to stop the coroutine of that specific target, but I don't know how.

I tried:

```
Coroutine b[i] = StartCoroutine(TargetDie(i, timeAlive/1000));
```

But that gives a syntax error. `b[i]` can't be used for Coroutines.

How to do this the proper way?

**Update:**

This is (the relevant part of) my TargetDie function:

```
IEnumerator TargetDie(int i, float delayTime)
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(delayTime);
    Destroy(targets[i]);
}
```

When the player kills the target, I do:

```
void Damage(int i)
{
   // at this time, the first Coroutine, started in InitiateKill, should stop, because otherwise it tries to destroy the target twice
   StartCoroutine(TargetDie(i, 0));
}
```

Comment: Do you store the number of the target somewhere? And if you want it to stop automatically, you can do that in the TargetDie function itself. It's worth explaining what this function is doing and when it should die/stop running

Comment: Yes, in it's name: target0, target1, ... How is that relevant for the coroutine part?

Comment: @Programmer: I've updated my question

Comment: Because first you should run the coroutine on the target so it stops automatically when it dies. Else you need to get some reference from the target so the target can propagate the fact that it dies. Or some loop that breaks the coroutine if the item is dead.

Comment: I understand how I can run the coroutine on the target. But all of my code, including the StartCoroutines, is on a different, empty GameObject called Controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply check for null before destroying it so that you won't get any error:

```
if (targets != null)
    Destroy(targets[i]);
```

But below is the recommended way if you want *to stop the old coroutine*.

---

You can use `Dictionary` to handle it. Use the `int i` as the key and `Coroutine` as the value.

When you call InitiateKill, add the `int i` to the dictionary and when you start the coroutine, add the `Coroutine` as the value in the dictionary too.

When `Damage` is called, check if that int value exist in the `Dictionary`. If it does, use it to retrieve the `Coroutine` value and stop the old coroutine. If it doesn't exit, start a new coroutine and then add it to that dictionary.

The dictionary should look like this:

```
Dictionary<int, Coroutine> dyingTarget = new Dictionary<int, Coroutine>();
```

Your new `InitiateKill` function which adds to the `Dictionary`:

```
void InitiateKill(int i)
{
    //i is the number of the target
    Coroutine crt = StartCoroutine(TargetDie(i, timeAlive / 1000));

    //Add to Dictionary
    dyingTarget.Add(i, crt);
}
```

Your new `Damage` function now checks if the item is already in the dictionary then retries it, stops the coroutine and removes it from the `Dictionary`.

```
void Damage(int i)
{
    // at this time, the first Coroutine, started in InitiateKill, should stop, because otherwise it tries to destroy the target twice
    StopIfAlreadyRunning(i);

    Coroutine crt = StartCoroutine(TargetDie(i, 0));
    //Add to Dictionary
    dyingTarget.Add(i, crt);
}

void StopIfAlreadyRunning(int i)
{
    Coroutine crtOut;
    //Retrieve and stop old coroutine if it exist then removes it
    if (dyingTarget.TryGetValue(i, out crtOut))
    {
        StopCoroutine(crtOut);
        dyingTarget.Remove(i);
    }
}
```

The new `TargetDie` function which removes it from the `Dictionary` after killing it. It also checks for `null` before destroying it:

```
IEnumerator TargetDie(int i, float delayTime)
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(delayTime);
    if (targets != null)
        Destroy(targets[i]);
    //Remove from Dictionary 
    dyingTarget.Remove(i);
}
```

Comment: This is brilliant, thanks for the answer and explanation!

Comment: Glad you find my answer helpful

Answer (score 1):

So most simple way, move the coroutine on the object itself.

```
public class DieScript: MonoBehaviour
{
    private Manager manager;
    public void StartDeathProcess(Manager manager)
    {
        this.manager = manager;
        StartCoroutine(DieAsync(manager));
    }
    private IEnumerator DieAsync(Manager manager)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(timer);
        Destroy(this.gameObject);
    }
    public void Dmaage() // This is register as listener for death of the object
    {
         this.manager.PropagateDeath(this);
         Destroy(this.gameObject);
    }
}

public class Manager:MonoBehaviour
{
    private List<DieScript> die;
    void InitiateKill(int i)  
    {
        die[i].StartDeathProcess(this);
    }
}
```

Trying to keep the control on the controller is about to bring more pain than solution.

You could have a list of IEnumerator to keep track of the running coroutines. But you still need a message from the object to inform the controller that it is dead. So you are missing this part.
You need a script on the target so the controller knows about this type. 
Controller runs the coroutine with a reference to that script asking each frame are you dying. When the target is meant to die, it sets a boolean to inform. Using Destroy keeps the object until end of frame so it would work out.

But this is doom to fail later on. It is kinda against programming concept to have a controller doing everything. You should see it more as a bypass for information.